# How to re-use drawRect code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to add a graphics effect / gradient, I have in a class for a UIView. I've chosen the class in the interface builder.

However now I'd like to re use it for a tableview. It won't let me select the same class for a tableview in interface builder.

I don't want to have to duplicate my drawing code, how can I move this?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
}
```

Comment: why not just put this custom view as a subview in a cell?

Comment: It's for the whole table view not a cell, it can change height too. I'm considering going back to the shadow approach but I have several views and I'd rather have one calling line of code than several for each. But I'm stuck on how to reuse this code too. I tried putting it in a method but it didn't add the layer, it seemed to loose the reference to the view without an error. Any ideas ?

Comment: put this view under your tableview, set tableview backgroundcolor to transparent and you won't have to subclass you tableview to achieve the same drawing behavior. If you totally need a separate classes - i suggest you to add `UIView` category method with name, say, `- (void)drawMySuperDuperGradient:(CGRect)rect` - and you'll be able to use it in any `UIView` descendant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead overriding drawRect you can use build-in layer shadow methods (in your subclass):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.yourTableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
    self.yourTableView.layer.shadowColor= [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually doing something more complicated with paint code, with multiple colours.

Comment: I've decided this is the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

I suggest saving your drawRect code to an image and then using a UIImageView instead of your custom view. That way it only gets drawn once. I made a convenience category for UIImage that I think is pretty neat.

```
@implementation UIImage (CustomImage)

+ (UIImage *)imageOfSize:(CGSize)size withBlock:(void (^)(CGContextRef context))drawingBlock{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, 0, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    drawingBlock(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```

You use it like this.

```
UIImage *myComplicatedPaintImage = [UIImage imageOfSize:tableViewCell.bounds.size withBlock:^(CGContextRef context) {

    //No need to fetch context, it is provided as block argument
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 123, 456);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,789,1011);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Then just keep a reference to that image and for all of your cells add it in an imageView.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:tableViewCell.bounds];
imageView.image = myComplicatedPaintImage;
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, Great idea, however the view may resize, hmm I guess I code add a tag, remove the image and add it again. It doesn't quite seem as simple. Or can you suggest a further enhancement ?

Comment: @Jules If you need multiple images then plain old drawRect is the way to go.  If you are trying to duplicate an image, use one image with multiple imageViews.

Comment: they will be different sizes, but I would like to reuse the code, as it will obey the frame size.

Comment: It depends if you know your sizes up front, if so just make all of your images ahead of time, this would be much faster than calling drawRect on the main thread while in use.  Even if you did have to make different sizes on the fly, I assume it would be markedly faster to create an image and duplicate it across all your cells than it would be to call drawRect for each cell. I have not measured this so who knows, but DrawRect is known to be slow, and that would minimize the Core Graphics calls either way.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, although I ended up going with the easier approach, granted doesn't look as good.